# The Meaning of The Ehrenfest Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

This may be a silly question, but could anyone inform me as to what the [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) means for the relation between classical and quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehrenfest's theorem, named after the Austrian physicist Paul Ehrenfest, states that the classical laws of motion hold (approximately) for the quantum mechanical expectation values of observables. For example, for the expectation value of momentum and the expectation value of the gradient of the potential energy (force) holds Newton's second law: $$\frac {d \langle \hat p\rangle}{dt}=-\langle \nabla V(\vec r) \rangle=\langle F(\vec r)\rangle$$ Similar relations hold for the time derivative of the expectation values of other QM operators. The theorem can thus be considered to be a justification of the laws of classical mechanics by the laws of QM.

Comment: How could one enunciate Ehrenfest’s theorem?

Comment: You can find a good descriptions in Merzbacher, Quantum Mechanics, 3rd edition,  Chapter 3. There is also a specific chapter on Ehrenfest's theorem in Messiah, Quantum Mechanics, Volume I, 1967, section VI.